# Merging/adding hashes in array with same key

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes:

```
array = [
  {"points": 0, "block": 3},
  {"points": 25, "block": 8},
  {"points": 65, "block": 4}
]
```

I need to merge the hashes. I need the output to be:

```
{"points": 90, "block": 15}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the array as you mentioned in this structure:

```
array = [
  {"points": 0, "block": 3},
  {"points": 25, "block": 8},
  {"points": 65, "block": 4}
]
```

You can use the following code to achieve your goal:

```
result = {
  points: array.map{ |item| item[:points] }.inject(:+),
  block: array.map{ |item| item[:block] }.inject(:+)
}
```

You will get this result:

```
{:points=>90, :block=>15}
```

**Note**: This will iterate twice over the array. I'm trying to figure out a better way to iterate once and still have the same elegant/easy to ready code.

If you want to do it more generically (more keys than `:points` and `:block`), then you can use this code:

```
array = [
  {"points": 0, "block": 3},
  {"points": 25, "block": 8},
  {"points": 65, "block": 4}
]

keys = [:points, :block] # or you can make it generic with array.first.keys

result = keys.map do |key|
  [key, array.map{ |item| item.fetch(key, 0) }.inject(:+)]
end.to_h
```

Comment: Hmm i tried your given code and it gives me what I'm looking for. Thank you! But i actually have 24 keys so i have to map them each, I hope you can help me to strip down the code, I'll gladly appreciate it. And my array may contain 10+ hashes will it matter?

Comment: I've updated my code to be more generic where you can define a set of keys to be summed up. If you are talking about 10+ hashes and 24 keys, I would not be concerned about performance. I'd say it's a premature optimisation at this scale.

Answer (score 4):

You could [`merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge) the hashes together, adding the values that are in both hashes:

```
result = array.reduce do |memo, next_hash|
  memo.merge(next_hash) do |key, memo_value, next_hash_value|
    memo_value + next_hash_value
  end
end
result # => {:points=>90, :block=>15}
```

and if your real hash has keys that don't respond well to `+`, you have access to the `key`, you could set up a case statement, to handle the keys differently, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create method as below to get the result

```
def process_array(array)
   points = array.map{|h| h[:points]}
   block = array.map{|h| h[:block]}
   result = {}
   result['points'] = points.inject{ |sum, x| sum + x }
   result['block'] = block.inject{ |sum, x| sum + x }
  result
end
```

and calling the method with array input will give you expected result.

```
[54] pry(main)> process_array(array)
=> {"points"=>90, "block"=>15}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Enumerator [each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each_with_object), using a hash as object.

```
result = array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|e, h| h[:points] += e[:points]; h[:block] += e[:block] }
# => {:points=>90, :block=>15}
```

`Hash.new(0)` means [initialise the hash to default value](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-default) `0` for any keys, for example:

```
h = Hash.new(0)
h[:whathever_key] # => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in how the `reduce` method introduced by "Simple Lime" worked and also how it would benchmark against simple iteration over the array and over the keys of each hash.

Here is the code of the "iteration" approach:

```
Hash.new(0).tap do |result|
  array.each do |hash|
    hash.each do |key, val|
      result[key] = result[key] + val
    end
  end
end
```

I was surprised, that the "iteration" code performed 3 times better than the `reduce` approach.

Here is the benchmark code https://gist.github.com/landovsky/6a1b29cbf13d0cf81bad12b6ba472416